# Unable to locate adb when starting emulator

Tags: android, flutter, adb

I hope you all will be great. I'm new to android studio and flutter. My question might seem a bit funny to you but I'm seriously facing this issue . I've already wasted 7 hours finding the solution for it. When I launch `AVD MANAGER` I'm directed to the virtual device but once i click it I get an error message `UNABLE TO LOCATE ADB`. I did all what i got on this site like I uninstalled platform-tools folder and reinstalled it from `SDK manager`. I still get the same error. I uninstalled android studio multiple times but nothing worked for me.
Attached is the screenshot.
OS: WIN 10
Android studio 4.0[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation, but when I click "OK", my emulator starts normally. If you just want to use the emulator, it should start.

[image]

Comment: Yes , but it doesnot show output of my app. I mean I pressed OK it showed the virtual device but when I run my flutter app it doesn't show any response.

Answer (score 0):

First check if adb.exe is present under platform-tools and is not corrupted. If so, you just will need to add path(under project/settings) to get it working. For installation, use below :
open Studio settings>System settings> Android SDK> select SDK tool tab> select "Android SDK platform tool" and install

Comment: Thanks It solved my problem. I added path.and it worked. I followed path where my SDK was located for example C:\user\userName\AppData\android\sdk\platform-tools to environment variables and I restarted my pc it worked fine.

Comment: Great! good to know.

Comment: Hi @Khurram just for others benefit, would it be possible to mark this as correct answer? Thanks.

Comment: sure ! I have marked it